# Retrieving sequential numbers in a distributed system

Tags: algorithm, performance, queue, distributed-system

System consists of tens of peer servers (none of them is leader/master). 
To create an entity, service should acquire the next sequential number basing on some group key: there are different sequences for each group key.

Let's say to create instance of entity A, service has to get sequence with group key A, while to create entity B, service has to get sequence number with group key B.

Getting the same number twice is prohibited. Missing numbers are allowed.

Currently I have implemented solution with a RDBMS, having a record for each of the group keys and updating its current sequence value in a transaction:
`UPDATE SEQUENCES SET SEQ_ID=SEQ_ID + 1 WHERE KEY = ?`
However, this approach only allows to get 200-300 queries per seconds because of locking and synchronisation.

Another approach I consider is to have local buffer of sequences at the each node. Once buffer is empty, service queries DB to get the next batch of ids and store them locally: `UPDATE SEQUENCES SET SEQ_ID=SEQ_ID + 1000 WHERE KEY = ?` if the batch size is 1000. This may help to lower contention. However, if node goes down it loses all these acquired sequence numbers, which, if happened frequently, can lead to overflowing the maximum value of sequence (e.g. max int).

I don't know in advance, how many sequence numbers will be needed.
I don't want to introduce additional dependencies between servers and have one of them to generate sequence numbers and serving to the others.

1. What are the general ways to solve similar problems?
2. Which other RDBMS-based approaches can be considered?
3. Which other NOT RDBMS-based approaches can be considered?
4. What other problems can happen with local buffer solution?

Comment: I don't understand why you involve multiple servers since their sequence are independant from each other. You may as well trim down your problem as generating a sequence from only one server. no?
Then you just want an id different than the one before. Take the current time (Date.now()) concatenate it some 2-3 random numbers at the end and you have an increasing sequence (omit the rnd digits), unique (hence the random in case two concurrent request on same server).
Or better, use a UUID, ULID or even [ObjectId](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/objectid/)

Comment: Who said their sequences are independent? All the servers should share the same sequence within group key, it is not bound to just one server.
I need sequential numbers, not random numbers or dates

Comment: I assumed 1 server 1 group key. if n server can have the same group key, same holds. I insist: Look at (e.g) the definition of ObjectId. (and a date can be represented by a number...so is an alphanumeric word...). And also if you want increasing numbers by 1, I invite you to take into consideration what happens if you rollback but some ids have been stored in the nature already